# Is there a way to save user input into a permanent list that is saved even after the python program is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

I want to make a chatbot in python 3 that can learn on its own. I want it to be able to store data from the users input. How could I do this and keep it in a list so whenever i check back on it it will have new variables stored inside from different users.

Answer (score 1):

Store the data in a file. Learn about reading and writing to files. Some code you could use it:

```
# Saving the information
file = open("filename.txt","w")
file.write('|'.join(my_list))
file.close()
# To get the information just do 
file = open("filename.txt","r").read()
my_list = file.split("|")
# Magic you have your list back again!
```

There is a lot more to this so you should do some research about reading and writing to files.

https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html

Answer (score 0):

For data to persist outside the program life-cycle you will need some form of permanent storage. Plain text files are an easy way to do this, as answered by Elodin. You can use JSON formatting to associate the data with each user, for example: [{"username":"John","input":"data entered by user 1"},{"username":"Mary","input":"data entered by user 2"}]. A better way, however, would be to use something like SQL/SQLite to store your data.